# google maps V3 duplicate marker, only in IE7,8 IE 9 is fine

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, google-maps-api-3

You can see the duplicated marker in the included image, the marker to the right is the correct marker, the one to the left is a clone of the other one, it is not in the right place it can not be clicked, and stays in the same position relative to the "real" marker reqardless of zoom level.

Here is the code that generates the marker:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($(this.jobDiv).find(".map_canvas")[0], { 'zoom': 10, 'center': this.latlng, 'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'mapTypeControl': false, 'navigationControl': true, 'streetViewControl': false });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: this.latlng,
    title: this.markerLabel
});
```

[image: duplicate markers, IE7,8]

Comment: seems to me like these two markers are totally different in lat lng. can you put up a jsfiddle or show some code?

Comment: the marker to the right is clickable and is the intended marker the one to the left is not clickable and no matter what zoom level I'm at it is always just left of the "real" marker, its like a shadow

Comment: where are you getting this.latlng and this.markerLabel from?

Comment: I'm using an object that has public properties on it

Comment: go ahead and post the entire marker creation code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a CSS issue, I set {overflow:hidden!important;}, on the div containing the google map, turns out I needed {overflow:hidden;}, and now its fine. I'm not sure how that caused the problem but it is fixed now.